# my posts are saved as drafts

Tags: php

I have recently add this function found in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89767/how-to-increase-the-character-limit-for-post-name-of-200) to increase my posts title limit of charcters from 200 to custom length, the problem now is that when I click publish, the posts are saved as drafts and I can't publish it cause I have only 2 choices

- Pending review
- Draft

Here is the function I have added to my functions file:

```
<?php

     remove_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes' );

        // add our custom hook 
    add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'wpse8170_sanitize_title_with_dashes', 10, 3 );
    function wpse8170_sanitize_title_with_dashes( $title, $raw_title = '', $context = 'display' ) {
        $title = strip_tags($title);
        // Preserve escaped octets.
        $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
        // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
        $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
        // Restore octets.
        $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

        if (seems_utf8($title)) {
            if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
                $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
            }
            $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 1000); // <--- here is the trick!
        }

        $title = strtolower($title);
        $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
        $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);

        if ( 'save' == $context ) {
            // Convert nbsp, ndash and mdash to hyphens
            $title = str_replace( array( '%c2%a0', '%e2%80%93', '%e2%80%94' ), '-', $title );

                // Strip these characters entirely
                $title = str_replace( array(
                // iexcl and iquest
                '%c2%a1', '%c2%bf',
                // angle quotes
                '%c2%ab', '%c2%bb', '%e2%80%b9', '%e2%80%ba',
                // curly quotes
                '%e2%80%98', '%e2%80%99', '%e2%80%9c', '%e2%80%9d',
                '%e2%80%9a', '%e2%80%9b', '%e2%80%9e', '%e2%80%9f',
                // copy, reg, deg, hellip and trade
                '%c2%a9', '%c2%ae', '%c2%b0', '%e2%80%a6', '%e2%84%a2',
                // grave accent, acute accent, macron, caron
                '%cc%80', '%cc%81', '%cc%84', '%cc%8c',
            ), '', $title );

            // Convert times to x
            $title = str_replace( '%c3%97', 'x', $title );
        }

        $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
        $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
        $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
        $title = trim($title, '-');

        return $title;
    } ?>
```

Comment: Please try removing this script to confirm that this is causing the problem.

Comment: i have already do that before posting my question, im super sure this is the problem, what i did here was just changing sanitize_title_with_dashes function with another to increase to the length of permalink, now all my posts are saved as drafts for some reason i dont know

Comment: Looks like you got this snippet from an older wpse thread. It appears that WordPress has changed this function. Just be warned that even following the answer below (which I'm sure will work fine for now) may break if/when WordPress updates this again.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to copy the current function `sanitize_title_with_dashes` from https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.6/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1948 and change the following line:

```
$title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 200);
```

To this:

```
$title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 1000);
```

**Minor edit: Always refer to the source for the same version of WordPress you have installed. In most cases, it should be the current version.**

The script you are using does not match the current function from formatting.php ([compare differences here](https://www.diffchecker.com/3Jo4HfsD)). Particularly, the following two lines appear after the `if ( 'save' == $context )` condition is triggered in the original function:

```
$title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
$title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);
```

---

### Example

Below is the same function as `sanitize_title_with_dashes` renamed as your new function `wpse8170_sanitize_title_with_dashes`. Only the value in `utf8_uri_encode()` has been changed:

```
function wpse8170_sanitize_title_with_dashes( $title, $raw_title = '', $context = 'display' ) {
    $title = strip_tags($title);
    // Preserve escaped octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
    // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
    $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
    // Restore octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);
    if (seems_utf8($title)) {
        if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
                $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 1000);
    }
    $title = strtolower($title);
    if ( 'save' == $context ) {
        // Convert nbsp, ndash and mdash to hyphens
        $title = str_replace( array( '%c2%a0', '%e2%80%93', '%e2%80%94' ), '-', $title );
        // Convert nbsp, ndash and mdash HTML entities to hyphens
        $title = str_replace( array( '&nbsp;', '&#160;', '&ndash;', '&#8211;', '&mdash;', '&#8212;' ), '-', $title );
        // Strip these characters entirely
        $title = str_replace( array(
            // iexcl and iquest
            '%c2%a1', '%c2%bf',
            // angle quotes
            '%c2%ab', '%c2%bb', '%e2%80%b9', '%e2%80%ba',
            // curly quotes
            '%e2%80%98', '%e2%80%99', '%e2%80%9c', '%e2%80%9d',
            '%e2%80%9a', '%e2%80%9b', '%e2%80%9e', '%e2%80%9f',
            // copy, reg, deg, hellip and trade
            '%c2%a9', '%c2%ae', '%c2%b0', '%e2%80%a6', '%e2%84%a2',
            // acute accents
            '%c2%b4', '%cb%8a', '%cc%81', '%cd%81',
            // grave accent, macron, caron
            '%cc%80', '%cc%84', '%cc%8c',
        ), '', $title );
        // Convert times to x
        $title = str_replace( '%c3%97', 'x', $title );
    }
    $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
    $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
    $title = trim($title, '-');
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: thank you but that's not the problem, i have fix it myself, you can see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

i have fix it, the problem was that post_name column in posts table set at varchar(200) so i have change that to LONGTEXT cause the permalink always gets post_name from there when its set to postname, i have just add this to my functions file and then deactivate then activate my them

```
function change_tab_length() {
     global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix. "posts";
    global $charset_collate;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    global $db_version;

    $wpdb->get_var("alter table ".$table_name." change post_name post_name LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8");
}
add_action( 'init', 'change_tab_length');
```